# Display Value in Excel TextBox in one excel file while reading data from another excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I've a Excel VBA generating results into one excel file which keeps on running few SQl querie and keeps on refreshing every 10-15 minutes threshold. I would like to read/refresh the results periodically say every 10-15 mins into second excel file?

Not sure I explained properly but is this possible? I've VBA code running and generating results fine in one excel file, refreshing every 10 mins at the moment. But I stuck on second step where I like to read results from this file and display it into my new excel file.

Any thoughts or inputs welcome.

Thank you.
Zulfiqar

[image: This is the dashboard excel file where I want to display results into a textboxes which are in the other excel file (values in B2, B3,..in other screen shot attached)]

Above is the dashboard excel file where I want to display results into a textboxes which are in the other excel file (values in B2, B3,..in below screen shot attached)

[image: Below is the results file..]

Comment: Are you after just reloading it every 10/15 min? if so use 
Application.Wait Now + #0:10:01#

Comment: Yes, i've that working. My issue @Kyoujin is I want to display this results into another excel file. how do i do that?

Comment: Use `Workbooks.Open` to open the workbook and paste the value over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like below, it will copy your A1 from your current workbook and place the value into B2 of your template workbook:

```
 Sub sb_Copy_Save_Worksheet_As_Workbook()
    Dim workbookName As String
    workbookName = "C:/User/Me/test/mynewworkbook.xlsx"
    'set the path to your workbook
    Set otherWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(workbookName) 'open it
    otherWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    'change the sheet name above to the sheet you want to copy
    otherWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    'change the path above to where you want the new file saved
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @Xabier the thing is I've a template dashboard excel file ready and I would like to just read the value from the first sheet and render it into template dashboard excel file at a defined location where i've texfboxes placed.

Comment: I've updated my answer to open your existing template and save your worksheet into it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated my question with the screenshot and bit of explanation to get clear idea as to what I am trying to achive.

Comment: Updated my answer, this will take value from A1 in your current workbook and put it into B2 of your template,...

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").TextBox_188.Text = otherWorkbook.Sheets("Instrument Search Result").Range("B2") doesn't seem to work. any idea?

Comment: its a form control for sure

Comment: I would have written it as `otherWorkbook.Sheets("Instrument Search Result").Range("B2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").TextBox_188.Value` try it and let me know if you are still having issues...

Comment: Doesn’t seem to work. It gives error on that line saying “Object doesn’t support this property”

Comment: @ZulfiqarDholkawala Would you be able to share your spreadsheet, so I can have a look at it? I've tested it and it does work for me...

Comment: Upload it to somewhere like Google Drive and comment a link to it here...

Comment: ok will do from home as no permission to external drives. But when i do below it works fine:
Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = otherWorkbook.Sheets("Instrument Search Result").Range("B3")

But when i do:  Worksheets(1).TempNAV.Value = otherWorkbook.Sheets("Instrument Search Result").Range("B3")

I get error: Run-Time error '428'
Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @ZulfiqarDholkawala it is to do with the way you reference your Textbox, which if it is an ActiveX control then the code above will work fine, but as you used a Form Control, which needs to be referenced differently,...

Comment: got that @Xabier. works as expected with ActiveX control. I'll post my spreadsheet later when i get a chance from home to show exactly what I am trying to do. thanks for your help mate.